# Unzip 7z archive with password using bash script

Tags: bash, shell, 7zip

I want to unzip a folder with multiple *.7z archives, all with same password.

Unfortunately, using this:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    password="12345678"
    cd /server/disc/folders.../folderWithArchives
    for package in ./*.7z;
    do
    7z -x -P{$password} $package
    done
```

gives me

**Error:
Incorrect command line**

Have you any ideas how to fix it?

---

I've tried shellcheck and it gave me this:

```
#!/bin/bash
password="12345678"
cd /server/disc/folders.../folderWithArchives || exit
for package in ./*.7z;
do
7z -x -P$password "$package"
done
```

but it still doesn't work

---

OS: Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS

shell:  GNU bash, version 4.3.48

Comment: Have you run your script through shellcheck yet?

Comment: Which OS are you running on and how did you install it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. 
Everything works OK after only deleting '-' before 'x'.
Now it works and looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
password="12345678"
cd /server/disc/folders.../folderWithArchives || exit
for package in ./*.7z;
do
7z x -P$password "$package"
done
```